# Aliasing between C++ struct and std:vector element--why?

Tags: c++, stdvector

In C++, `csi` is a structure with integer fields:

```
struct CentScanInfo
{
    int runId;
...
};
```

The following code processes a vector of `csi` structures:

```
// Create vector of csi structures
CentScanInfo csi; std::vector<CentScanInfo> csiv;
for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    // ... code to store values into a csi structure
    csiv.push_back(csi);
}

// Sort the vector, then process entries
if(csiv.size() > 0)
{
    sort(csiv.begin(), csiv.end(), CsiSortCriterion);
    // BEFORE: csiv[n-2] = 3605406551, which is correct
    csi.pFI->runId = -99;
    // AFTER: csiv[n-2] = -99, which is wrong
    ...
}
```

I do not expect changing the variable `csi` to affect any element of the vector `csiv`. Why does this happen, and how should the code be changed so it does not occur?

Visual Studio 2017 15.4.5; 64-bit Windows 7 Pro

Comment: what's the csi.pFI?

Comment: Why are you using `->` when you just need to use `.` that is most likely it

Comment: I assume `cdi.pFI` is a pointer? It looks like every element may have the same value for that pointer (they all point to the same object)? You should probably include the code that contains `csi.pFI` so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Looks like your structure has pointers (pFI), which are copied into the vector. C++ does not do deep copying for you, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Whether it solves your problem or not familiarize yourself with the Rules of Zero, Three and Five: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three . Very important to know and can eliminate the insane amounts of debugging time required to learn the hard way.

Comment: This is a good example of why including a [mcve] is more than just a good idea.

Comment: pFI is a pointer to another structure, which contains an integer field runId. The pFI in different elements of the csiv vector are not the same, and the structures they point to are distinct (and contain expected values). Neither csi nor FI (structure pointed to by pFI) contains a user-defined destructor, a user-defined copy constructor, or a user-defined copy assignment operator.

Comment: You say `CentScanInfo` has integer fields but then you use `->` operator on one. That operator cannot be used on an integer

Answer (score 0):

The aliasing is taking place via the `pFI` pointer. In the first loop, where the vector is populated, each `csi` has a unique `pFI`. Thus, when `csi` is used following the sort, `csi.pFI` is the same as the final element of the vector (before sorting).

The fix is to add another `FI` object, and set its `pFI` field, before changing `runId`:

```
CFileInfo sentinel; csi.pFI = &sentinel;
```

This should have been obvious, but obviously it wasn't!